# JAVA: regex for matching both `int` and `double`

Tags: java

In java what should be the regex for matching both `int` and `double`.

I have following sample:

`4 TO 6.1` `4.3 TO 3.5` `3 TO 5`

I tried below one but its failing with `4.1 TO 6`

```
"4.1 TO 6".trim().matches("\\d.+\\sTO\\s\\d.+")
```

Comment: Try this: `\\d.+\\.\\d+\\sTO\\s\\d+`

Comment: What is the problem with this question for -ve voting

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but i think they downvoted because your issue can be resolved by searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this one:

```
\d+\.?\d*\WTO\W\d+\.?\d*
```

To check if you have an int or decimal in either side, with just one and just one space between the numbers and TO.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regexp you need: `"\\d.*\\d*\\sTO\\s*\\d.*"`

Comment: but its also matching `4     TO 6` there should be only one space before after `TO`

Answer (score 0):

For more general:

`[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\\sTO\\s[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`

**See also:**

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "\\d*(\\.\\d*)?+\\sTO\\s\\d*(\\.\\d*)?";
    System.out.println("4 TO 6.1".trim().matches(regex));
    System.out.println("4.3 TO 3.5".trim().matches(regex));
    System.out.println("3 TO 5".trim().matches(regex));
    System.out.println("4.1 TO 6".trim().matches(regex));
}
```

\d* check the first digits, (\.\d*)? check it there is decimals, after you check space TO space and the same expression as before.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`"4.1 TO 6".trim().matches("\\d+\\.{0,1}\\d*\\sTO\\s\\d+\\.{0,1}\\d*")`